# preg_replace_callback not working in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

```
$str="Your LaTeX document can \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{test}\DIFaddend be easily 
and the text can have multiple lines in it like this\DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{test2}
\DIFaddend"
```

I need to convert all `\DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{test}\DIFaddend` to `\added{test}`.

I tried

```
$o= preg_replace_callback('/\\DIFaddbegin\\s\DIFadd{(.*?)}\\DIFaddend/',
function($m) {return preg_replace('/$m[0]/','\added{$m[1]}',$m[0]);},$str);
```

But no luck. Which would be correct pattern for this? And also even if the string contains new line character the pattern should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a callback, using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is fine for this task. To match a single backslash you need to double escape it meaning `\\\\`. To match possible whitespace between each substring, you can use `\s*` meaning whitespace "zero or more" times.

```
$str = preg_replace('~\\\\DIFaddbegin\s*\\\\DIFadd({[^}]*})\s*\\\\DIFaddend~', '\added$1', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new_str = preg_replace("/\\\\DIFaddbegin \\\\DIFadd\{(.*)\}\\\\DIFaddend/s","\\added{\$1}",$str);
```